# Sum and Count queries taking exceptionally long time

Tags: mysql, count, sum, innodb

I am aware that there are other questions on this same topic.  I have read through all of them, and have not found an answer that helps my situation.  Maybe that means there is no solution...

I am using innodb.  I have a table that looks like this:

```
`feature` varchar(255) primary key 
`1` int default 0 
`2` int default 0 
...
`33` int default 0
```

I need to get the sum of the values in any column, and the count of each column (where the row value is not 0).

The last query I ran was:

```
select count(*), sum(`1`) from spec_unigrams_temp where `1` <> 0
```

I have tried many others.  That last query took 450 seconds to run!

Is there anything I can do to get that time down?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your question with the table definition or at least do you have an index on 1?

Comment: Do you really have a column called `1`???

Comment: Yes.  The column refers to a primary key in another table.

Comment: I would start that columns as just numeric names is not cool and could be seen as very confusing...  So the 33, you have 33 tables in your system and this appears to be a master record linking them all together?  Also, how many records in this "spec_unigrams_temp" table

Comment: There are no foreign keys on the table.  I agree that the numbered columns are confusing and spent some time thinking about whether I should do it that way or not, but decided it simplifies things to do it with numbered columns in this case.  There are a couple hundred thousand rows, about 300k at last count.  It will likely balloon to a few million in a couple days.